# How to follow changes in a dataframe, but only in one direction

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to simulate a [trailing stop](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_(exchange)#Trailing_stop_order), used in trading.

Some data:

```
(input) (output)
price   peg
1000    0995  set a price - 5
1001    0996  following price up
1002    0997  following price up
1001    0997  not following price down
1010    1005  following price up
1012    1007  following price up
1010    1007  not following price down
1006    STOP  the price went below the last peg
```

The logic is the following:

- I start by setting a *peg* at -5, so it takes price - 5 and makes 995.
- Each time the price goes up, the peg follows up, always keeping a -5 gap
- If the price goes down, the peg does NOT go down
- If the price goes below, or equal to the peg, I need to know the index and the process RESTARTS

Is there a Pandas idiomatic way to do this? I've implemented it as a loop, but it is very slow.

This is some code I've done for the loop:

```
# i is the index at which we take a trade in
# and I want to go through the rest of the dataframe to see if it would
# hit a trailing stop

if direction == +1:  # only long trades in this example
    peg_price = entry_price -5
    for j in range(i + 1, len(df)):
        low = df['low'][j]
        if low <= peg_price:
            date = df['date'][i]

            trade_date.append(df['date'][i])
            trade_exit_date.append(df['date'][j])
            trade_price.append(entry_price)
            trade_exit.append(peg_price)
            trade_profit.append(peg_price - entry_price)
            skip_to = j + 1
        else:
            low = df['high'][j]
            peg_price = max(high - 5, peg_price)
```

The example is a bit more complex because I need to compare the peg with the 'low' price but update it with the 'high' price; but the idea is there.

Comment: Can you share what you did so far?

Comment: I just added some code example; it's a bit more complex than in the question: in practice, I'm using the high and low prices for the peg: make sure the low didn't hit the peg, but move the peg based on the high one. I made the question about a single price to make it simpler

Comment: since the value to produce is not a direct function of a fixed number of preceding rows/columns, I would say there is no *idiomatic* way of doing this. You'll have to iterate the rows, keeping track of previous peg values - same as in the existing approach.

Comment: are the increments always in steps of 1 ?

Comment: through the index, yes, I go row by row; the process can be broken down though where I need to find, for a range of value if the peg is touched (and at which index). Then I can restart the process for another range. The price values can vary significantly from one row to the next

Comment: sorry - I mean if the price goes up in an increment of one, does condition of keeping a -5 gap stay true?

Comment: Yes, the peg is always max(price -5, last_peg)

Answer (score 1):

IIUC:

```
data = {"price":[1000,1001,1002,1001,1010,1012,1010,1006]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# first make a column of price-5
df["peg"] = df["price"]-5

# use np.where to check whether price dropped or increased
df["peg"] = np.where(df["price"].shift()>df["price"],df["peg"].shift(),df["peg"])

print (df)

   price     peg
0   1000   995.0
1   1001   996.0
2   1002   997.0
3   1001   997.0
4   1010  1005.0
5   1012  1007.0
6   1010  1007.0
7   1006  1005.0

# Get the index of STOP
print (df[df["peg"].shift()>df["peg"]])

   price     peg
7   1006  1005.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way,

the idea is to pass all your logical conditions into true false booleans, we can then iteratively step through the assignments and pass them in. Once we have done that we can find the row where the `peg` is greater then the `price` we can then assign `STOP` if you have data that you need to NA after this you can easily to a logical `.loc` and assign any values after stop to NA.

for this example I've used your peg column name as counter so we can compare.

```
import pandas as pd
peg1 = df['price'].sub(df['price'].shift(1)) == 1 # rolling cumcount

peg2 = df['price'].sub(df['price'].shift(1)) > 1 # -5 these vals

peg3 = df['price'].sub(df['price'].shift(1)) <= -1 # keep as row above.
#assignments

df.loc[peg1,'counter'] = df['counter'].ffill() + peg1.cumsum()
df.loc[peg2,'counter'] = df['price'] - 5
df.loc[peg3,'counter'] = df['counter'].ffill()

df.loc[df['counter'] > df['price'], 'counter'] = 'STOP'

print(df)
   price   peg counter
0   1000  0995     995
1   1001  0996     996
2   1002  0997     997
3   1001  0997     997
4   1010  1005    1005
5   1012  1007    1007
6   1010  1007    1007
7   1006  STOP    STOP
```